# Can't resume after suspend and power off issues with ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, suspend, power-management, shutdown

I installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu on my desktop computer and now I face several power related issues:

#### Can't resume after I suspend the system:

When I suspend the system, it screen goes blank and there is a white dash blinking. All the fans and lights stay on, and if I hit a key on the keyboard or move the mouse the system does not wake up.

#### System is power on when suspended

All lights and fans are still running when I click suspend

#### Can't power off the system

When I click shut down the system goes blank with a white dash blinking and all fans and lights are on.

## Steps I tried:

- I tried to disable all power saving settings in the bios
- I tried to use proprietary drivers for nvidia
- I updated everything
- I **can't** power off system with this command `sudo init 0`
- I **can't** power off system with this command `sudo shutdown -P now`
- I **can't** power off system with this command `sudo shutdown -H now`
- Changing grup to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"` doesnt change anything
- I read this [documentation page](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/power-suspendfail.html) and didn't help
- To power off the computer I must press and hold the power button for 5 seconds and do a hard power off

## System Spec:

- 128GB SSD
- GeForce GTX 560 Ti (using the x.org x server open source driver)

It is been two days and I have been trying to search and fix this issue but I can't get it to work. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Can you turn of certain P and C states in the BIOS?

Comment: @Zacharee1 which parts? how can I find them?

Comment: They would be in the BIOS settings if you can change them.

Comment: @Zacharee1 my bios is something like this: http://images.anandtech.com/doci/5714/MSI%20BIOS%2010%20-%20HW%20Monitor.png I should find this in the boots section or power management ?

Comment: Power management, I believe.